# gitkraken push failure to a kerberos-authenticated server

Tags: kerberos, fedora-25, gitkraken

I'm trying to use GitKraken 2.6.0 on a Fedora 25 client. The remote  repository is located on a remote server with Kerberos authentication. The local repository was cloned over ssh. I can successfully execute all git commands from the command line, also with the SmartGit GUI. GitKraken is configured to use the local ssh client. The local repository is one commit ahead of the remote. On an attempt to push, GitKraken GUI first prompts for the user name to use and then generates the following error diagnostics : "Push failed. Unrecognized Allowed Types: 0". Any insight on what that means would be much appreciated.  Thanks!